# Uneeded space in div container

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am creating a theme for Tumblr, so it's not all raw HTML. For some reason, I am getting a space above my picture caption. It should be about the same size of padding as my text posts (as you can see in the image: http://puu.sh/5x85e.png). I've Googled it and nothing  comes up for this. Either that or I'm wording it wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>

    {Title}{block:PostSummary}, {PostSummary}{/block:PostSummary}

</title>

{block:Description}

    <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />

{/block:Description}

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style type="text/css">

    body {
        font-family: roboto;
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
        margin-top: 10px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width: 500px;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .content {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    }

   .title img {
       border-radius: 100%;
       margin-right:10px;
       float:left;
   }

   .title a {
       font-weight: 700;
       color:#000;
       text-decoration: none;
   }

   .title a:hover {
       text-decoration: underline;
   }

   .body {
       font-weight: 400;
       font-size: 13px;
       color: #404040;
   }

   .dateNote {
       font-weight: 400;
       font-size: 12px;
       color: #909090;
   }

   .tags {
       font-size:12px;
   }

   .tags a {
       font-weight: 400;
       color: #909090;
       text-decoration: none;
   }

   .postPhoto img {
       max-width:100%; 
       max-height:100%;
   }

   .caption {
       font-weight: 700;
       color:#000;
       text-decoration: none;
   }

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        {block:Posts}

            <div class="content">

            <!-- Text Posts -->

                {block:Text}

                    <div class="title">

                        {block:Title}

                            <img src="{PortraitURL-40}" />

                            <a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>

                        {/block:Title}

                    </div>

                    <div class="dateNote">

                        {NoteCount} Notes &nbsp; — &nbsp; {TimeAgo}

                    </div>

                    <div class="body">

                        {Body}

                    </div>

                {/block:text}

                <!-- End Posts -->

                <!-- Photo Posts -->

                {block:Photo}

                {block:Caption}

                        <div class="caption">

                            {Caption}

                        </div>

                    {/block:Caption}

                    <a class="postPhoto">

                    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />


                    </a>

                {/block:Photo}

                <!-- End Photo Posts -->

                <!-- Tags -->

                {block:HasTags}

                        <div class="tags">

                            {block:Tags}

                                <a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag} </a>

                            {/block:Tags}

                        </div>

                {/block:HasTags}

                <!-- End Tags -->

            </div>

        {/block:Posts}

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why dont you send the link of the tumblr? to make it easier to test it.

Comment: It's http://bfgsdfdfgdfgsdfg.tumblr.com/ I really didn't want to think of a creative name since I'm just designing my them on this one then porting it over to my main blog. Also, for some reason, my caption is repeating itself three times now and I haven't even touch the code except for trying something, which didn't work so I just ctrl+z'd it to it's original form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
.caption p {
  margin: 2px 0 !important;
}
```

done.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Also just wondering, do you know why my caption is repeating itself? It seems like tumblr is doing it for some reason. It does it randomly for some stuff.

Comment: i know why downvoters downvoted, its because that was applying to all `p`'s of the whole document, but ok downvoters now it only applies to the caption.

Comment: @ErraticFox maybe its a theme default behaviour.

Comment: I hate the downvoting culture here. They couldve left a msg / suggestion to improve the answer. Too many down-vote happy nerds here. I hope you keep posting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML so I can't tell for sure what's the documents structure

It seems like the caption is a header or a paragraph element which has 1em `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` asigned by the browser's user agent (notice green area in the image below). Try removing either the caption's margin-top (top part of green area) or the caption container's `padding-top` (top part of red area).

[image]

**edit**:

"This is a caption, just for a test" was actually a paragraph, just as I predicted.
Targeting all `p` elements will ruin the design of your blog. You should instead target the caption's paragragh only, by using the following selector `.caption p`

```
.caption p{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I see. I tried both margin-top: 0px; and padding-top: 0px; in my .caption CSS. Still nothing... I don't know why this could be happening.

Comment: "This is a caption, just for a test" was actually a paragraph, just as I predicted. Targeting all `p` elements will ruin the design of your blog. You should istead target the caption's paragragh only by using the following selector `.caption p`